# Static don't load in Django CMS

Tags: django, static, django-cms

Static files don't load after I moved them to another directory. 

My **settings.py** looks like this:

```
DATA_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'src', 'static'),
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder"
)
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ...
)
```

All the static I want to place in the root directory of my virtualenv. There are folders

```
src(root_dir)-->media      /* uploaded media */
             -->static     /* for css, js etc*/
             -->project_y  /*web-page*/
             -->templates  /*html templates */
```

The strange thing (for me) is that templates and media works normally from that directories. I've placed them this way:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'
)
```

Any ideas how to relocate that static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Static Files, you have to `collectstatic`

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Will collect files from all the `STATICFILES_DIRS` and place them inside the `STATIC_ROOT`. Only after this, the static files can be accessed

Comment: I've got another message now. Python says that `No such files or directory: '/home/stp/web/project_y/src/src/static'`. Of course there is no such dir, I've got `/home/stp/web/project_y/src/static`. Something wrong with path in settings.py :(

Comment: @StPavel You have specified `/src/src/static` in `STATICFILES_DIRS`. Change it to any of the existing directories and it will work fine. If you have problems, what is the path of the files that you want to copy to static folder?

Comment: My static files right now placed in `/src/project_y/static/` and all works OK. But I want all the static files place in `/src/static/`. If I set `STATICFILE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')` and do `collectstatic` then message appears `The STATICFILES_DIRS settings should not contain the STATIC_ROOT settings`.

Comment: `STATIC_ROOT` should be the directory where you want the static files to be, which in your case is `/src/static/`. `STATICFILES_DIRS` are the directories from where the files have to be fetched during collectstatic. So, I think you have interchanged both the directories

Comment: I got it! I've changed `STATICFILES_DIRS` to `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project_y', 'static')`. All the static was collected correctly. But now i got another question - how to make djangocms to use static folder which was filled up by `collecstatic` command?

Comment: by default, all of the django apps use the `STATIC_ROOT` property